# nginx tcp forward to multiple IPs

Tags: nginx, networking, tcp, proxy

I was looking on the documentation to make [nginx as a reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/#upstream) for TCP connections. It talks about Load Balancing strategies....

What I wanted to know is how can I forward a TCP request to 2 different IPs simultaneously. Basically 1 source and 2 drains. Every request from the source is duplicated and sent to 2 drains every time. (Like a tee pipe for TCP, or a TCP duplicator)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't want to drift too far away from your question, but if I had that problem I would let nginx refer to another program (C++,Shell,PHP,Python). The program can then decide what to do with this client.

As mentioned I don't want to drift too far away from your question, but some pseudocode for my solution would be:

```
int server = 30012; //clients
int server1 = 120; //clients

if(server1 < server)
{
   redirect to server1;
}else{
   redirect to server;
}
```